# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded with sudoku solver

Tags: javascript

```
// global variable
// accessible to all functions
var sol =
    [[0, 7, 0, 2, 3, 8, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 8, 0, 9],
    [0, 6, 8, 1, 0, 9, 0, 0, 2],
    [0, 3, 5, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8],
    [6, 0, 7, 8, 0, 2, 5, 0, 1],
    [8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 7, 6, 0],
    [2, 0, 0, 6, 0, 3, 1, 9, 0],
    [7, 0, 9, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 9, 7, 4, 0, 8, 0]];
//this function prints the board
var printBoard = function () {
    for (let row = 0; row < sol.length; row += 1) {
        for (let col = 0; col < sol[row].length; col += 1) {
            let id = 'r' + (row + 1) + (col + 1);
            let elem = document.getElementById(id);
            elem.innerHTML = sol[row][col];
        }
    }
};

function isValid(sol, row, col, k) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        const m = 3 * Math.floor(row / 3) + Math.floor(i / 3);
        const n = 3 * Math.floor(col / 3) + i % 3;
        if (sol[row][i] == k || sol[i][col] == k || sol[m][n] == k) {
          return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

var solve = function() {
    for (let row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
        for (let col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
            if (sol[row][col] == 0) {
                for (let k = 1; k <= 9; k++) {
                    if (isValid(sol, row, col, k) == true) {
                        sol[row][col] == '${k}';
                        if(solve() == true) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            sol[row][col] == 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

printBoard();
```

I am having trouble debugging this. I keep getting an error message when I click on my solve button, which will take the grid and complete a sudoku puzzle: "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". Looking at the file, it seems that my isValid() function, is causing the issues here. I think I am stuck in a continuous loop somewhere? Any help would be appreciated. It also says the error lies on lines 40 and 24, which are:

```
function isValid(sol, row, col, k) {
```

and

```
if (isValid(sol, row, col, k) == true) {
```

Please help, as I am not even a CS major and this is for a class requirement, and I am not exactly experience with this type of stuff. I tried to search for help thorugh other resources but it is just confusing me even more.

EDIT:

```
//global variable
//accesible to all functions
var sol =
    [[0, 7, 0, 2, 3, 8, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 8, 0, 9],
    [0, 6, 8, 1, 0, 9, 0, 0, 2],
    [0, 3, 5, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8],
    [6, 0, 7, 8, 0, 2, 5, 0, 1],
    [8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 7, 6, 0],
    [2, 0, 0, 6, 0, 3, 1, 9, 0],
    [7, 0, 9, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 9, 7, 4, 0, 8, 0]];
//this function prints the board
var printBoard = function () {
    for (let row = 0; row < sol.length; row += 1) {
        for (let col = 0; col < sol[row].length; col += 1) {
            let id = 'r' + (row + 1) + (col + 1);
            let elem = document.getElementById(id);
            elem.innerHTML = sol[row][col];
        }
    }
};

function isValid(sol, row, col, k) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        const m = 3 * Math.floor(row / 3) + Math.floor(i / 3);
        const n = 3 * Math.floor(col / 3) + i % 3;
        if (sol[row][i] == k || sol[i][col] == k || sol[m][n] == k) {
          return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

var solve = function(sol) {
    for (let row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
        for (let col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
          if (sol[row][col] == 0) {
              //set the check for the row and column
            for (let k = 1; k <= 9; k++) {
              if (isValid(sol, row, col, k) == true) {
                sol[row][col] == k;
                //check if its not true, then check the row and column again
              if(solve() == true) {
               return true;
              } else {
               sol[row][col] = 0;
              }
             }
           }
           return false;
         }
       }
     }
     return true;
    };

printBoard();
```

Comment: I think the problem is that isValid() is getting called a bunch of times, and each time it's run, it loops 9 times.

Comment: any way to fix this? I am completely lost

Comment: The problem is that you recursively call `solve()` function. Each time you call a function it increases the stack and each time the function finishes the stack is decreased. You might need to rework your algorithm a bit to reduce the recursive calls.

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to brute force the sudoku. The number of combinations will be massive, far greater than a stack can handle. Like @Luka said, converting your recursion to using a loop will eliminate recursion

Answer (score 1):

You never change `sol` before recursively calling `solve()` again.

```
if (isValid(sol, row, col, k) == true) {
    sol[row][col] == '${k}'; // <- does not update sol
    if(solve() == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        sol[row][col] == 0; // <- does not update sol
    }
}
```

When you find an option for `k` that is a valid you should update `sol` before calling `solve()` again. Otherwise you will create an endless recursive loop which will eventually exceed the maximum stack size and result in the error you receive.

Use the [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment) (`=`) instead of the [equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) (`==`) to assign a new value. Furthermore `'${k}'` will result in the literal `${k}` use [backticks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (`` ` ``) if you want to use string interpolation. I don't see a reason to use a string here, simply assigning `k` would be sufficient.

```
if (isValid(sol, row, col, k) == true) {
    sol[row][col] = k; // <- assign k to a cell in the matrix
    if(solve() == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        sol[row][col] = 0; // <- reset the cell back to 0 if it cannot be solved
    }
}
```

---

I would also suggest using [guard clauses](http://wiki.c2.com/?GuardClause). Instead of nesting the whole body of the for-loop inside an if-statement, use a guard and skip to the next iteration with [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue):

```
for (...) {
    if (check) {
        // code
    }
}
```

Can be changed to:

```
for (...) {
    if (!check) continue;
    // code
}
```

This generally improves the code indention and readability.

Comment: Thank you so much! My new code is in the edit, but now when I click on the Solve button, it does not output anything. ANy tips?

Comment: 1. Your edited version still uses `sol[row][col] == k`, and not `sol[row][col] = k` 2. Have you checked the result with `console.log(sol)` or `console.table(sol)`? Not outputting to the HTML might be different problem.